# Construction of a corner of a diagram out of the homotopy pushout

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, limits-colimits, model-categories

Let \begin{array}{ccc} X & \xrightarrow{} & Y \\ \downarrow & & \downarrow\\ Z & \xrightarrow{} & W\\ \end{array} be a homotopy commutative diagram in a proper model catgeory $\mathcal{C}$ with $P$ be the homotopy pushout of the diagram $Z \leftarrow X \to Y.$

Consider the following (homotopy)commutative diagram

[image]

with $Y' \to Y, Z'\to Z, W'\to W$ and $P' \to P$ are weak equivalences. Can we construct $X'$ such that **$X' \to X$ will be weak equivalence and $X'Y'Z'W'$, $X'Y'XY$, and $X'XZ'Z$ are homotopy commutative?**

Thank you so much in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You write (homotopy) commutative-but which is it? It makes a big difference whether you want strict or homotopy commutativity! Presumably you also want maps $X’\to Y’,Z’$, right? If homotopy commutativity is enough, you can just take the homotopy limit of everything you have there.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Everything is homotopy commutative. Also, the final line "...$X' \to X$ will be homotopy commutative.

Comment: @KevinCarlson: You mean $X'$ is the homotopy pullback of the diagram $Z' \to W' \leftarrow Y'$. If it is so, then why $X' \to X$ will be a weak equivalence?

Comment: @KevinCarlson: Yes, I want $X'$ such that $X' \to X$ is a week equivalence and $X'Y'Z'W'$, $X'Y'XY$, and $X'XZ'Z$ are homotopy commutative.

Comment: No, the homotopy limit of the entire diagram, at least including $X,Y,Z,W,Y’,Z’,W’$. But I was speaking too fast in claiming that even then $X’\to X$ is an equivalence.

Comment: This is the third question of this type asked by the OP in the last 2 days.  Perhaps the underlying motivation should be explained first, since we may have a case of the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov: The underlying motivation is as follows: Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two strict commutative squares \begin{array}{ccc} X & \xrightarrow{f} & Y \\ \downarrow{g} && \downarrow \\ Z & \xrightarrow{} & W_i\end{array}, for $i=1,2$ in a proper model category. Here $X, Y$ and $Z$ are cofibrants and $f$ and $g$ are cofibrations. So we have two canonical maps $\beta_i: P \to W_i$ where $P$ is the pushout of the diagram $Z \leftarrow X \to Y.$ I want to prove that if there is a zigzag of equivalences from $\beta_1$ to $\beta_2$ then so is from $D_1$ to $D_2$